# get value from address bar in query string

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
http://192.168.0.4/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance?child=80000008&datefrom=03%2F01%2F2014&dateto=04%2F30%2F2014
```

When this is present in address bar, then I easily get values for both :child id and date .
On going to the next page using pagination, URL changes to :

```
http://192.168.0.4/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance?child=80000008&datefrom=03%2F01%2F2014&dateto=04%2F30%2F2014/2
```

In this case, I am not able to get the values of child id and date.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: you cannot combine query string then after uri setup. What you can do is that add an additional parameter something like `&page=2` for your pagination or in something like `/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/2/viewPerformance?child=....` but this require rerouting or just use URI routing

Comment: Can you please be more specific when you say that you are not able to get the child id and date values ? How are you doing it at first place .. I can not see a reason why you are not able to do it once and not other time .

Comment: i search child information between two dates. i use get method in form. first time it work well but when i use pagination then "/2" add after url then i not able to gat all query strings values.

Comment: Are you using the $_GET array or parsing the url string? Its not clear

Comment: did you try this $this->input->get('child');

Comment: i route this .. $route['TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance/per/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance';  nut it not working. @DrixsonOseña

Comment: i use  this to get values..$datefrom1 = trim($this->input->get('datefrom'));
   $datefrom = strtotime($datefrom1);
   $dateto1 = trim($this->input->get('dateto'));
   $dateto = strtotime($dateto1);
   $child = trim($this->input->get('child'));

Answer (score 1):

if you're gonna use URI routing it should be something like this:

you're URL:

`http://192.168.0.4/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance?child=80000008&datefrom=03%2F01%2F2014&dateto=04%2F30%2F2014&page=2`

Then you can put a line in your config/routes.php :

```
$routes['/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance?child=(:any)&datefrom=(:any)&dateto=(:any)/(:num)'] = '/allonkid/TaskControlPanel/viewPerformance/$1/$2/$3/$4'
```

where

```
$1 = child
$2 = datefrom
$3 = dateto
$4 = page // pagination
```

This can be modified depending on what you need. My tip is not to just copy and paste my answer but understand the process also make sure query string is enable in your config

Then process it by using URI segmentation

Comment: thnkx but in my pagination function in library i use "/pageno." like "/2" so i dont want to change it. please solve in this way..please..

Comment: @Jitendra updated i removed `/page=` and changed it to `/(:num)`, seems you're not familiar using routing.. you should read how to use it.

Comment: i know very well routing. :) . i use this i get all values but 'dateto' not get yet. all variables are correct.